# Как осуществляется проверка в Vue?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Разрабатываю приложение на laravel+vue, и возникло пару вопросов:

1. Как в компоненте Vue сделать такую проверку, типа `@guest Login/Register @else Logout @endguest`
2. Как передать `Auth::id()` в компонент? Как его в компоненте вывести?
3. Сайт у меня будет почти весь в картинках, разумно ли на каждую картинку вешать router-link... типа, чтоб у каждой картинки был свой url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1,2. Во `view.blade.php` передаем параметром в компонент
`<you-login-component id="{{Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->id : 0}}"/>`.
В компоненте получаем его используем, соответственно если `id` то пользователь авторизован и вот его `id` иначе не авторизован

    `export default{
        props: ["id"],
        mounted(){
            console.log(this.id)
        }
    }`

3. Недостаточно информации, чтоб понять цель. Если у вас картинка это ссылка, скажем на какой-либо пост, то разумно сделать один роут вида `{path: '/posts/:id'}`